# How to mix JQuery UI's draggable and sortable with div elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

In this Fiddle I am trying to mix JQuery UI's `draggable` and `sortable` utilities, the problem is that for some reason my `<div>` elements get moved around strangely when I drag & drop them. I think it might come from the `display: inline-block;` property but I can't remove it. How can I get rid of this annoying side-effect?

[jsfiddle.net/Zh83n](http://jsfiddle.net/Zh83n/2/)

Note: tested on Chrome only since it's the only browser I have to support for my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just trying to make a single list sortable, `.draggable()` is redundant. Check out http://jsfiddle.net/peterjmag/Zh83n/3/ for an example.

**HTML**

```
<div id="sortable">
    <div class="disp">Test1</div>
    <div class="disp">Test2</div>
    <div class="disp">Test3</div>
    <div class="disp">Test4</div>
    <div class="disp">Test5</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.disp {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**JS**

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    revert: true
});

/*
$(".disp").draggable({
    connectToSortable: "#sortable",
    revert: "invalid"
});
*/
```

(I've just commented out the redundant draggable call for reference.)

Note that my fiddle still has some spacing issues, which are indeed related to `display: inline-block`. Check out the following answer for a couple of different approaches to that problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14317901/349353.